# How to take product of two list in OCaml?

Tags: list, ocaml

I have two lists :

```
let a = ["a";"b"];
let b = ["c";"d"];
```

I want an output list c such as :

```
c = ["a";"c";"a";"d";"b";"c";"b";"d"];
```

How to do it in ocaml as lists are immutable? I am new to it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would return a new list. If you really are interested in the *cartesian product* of the lists, then this should be enough:

```
let cartesian l l' = 
  List.concat (List.map (fun e -> List.map (fun e' -> (e,e')) l') l)

# cartesian ["a";"b"] ["c";"d"];;
- : (string * string) list = [("a", "c"); ("a", "d"); ("b", "c"); ("b", "d")]
```

If you need that strange flat structure instead, you can use an additional list concatenation.

```
let flat_cartesian l l' = 
  List.concat (List.concat (
    List.map (fun e -> List.map (fun e' -> [e;e']) l') l))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to use concatenation, because this is not a tail recursive operation, you can use the following (which should be more efficient):

```
let product l1 l2 =
  List.rev (
   List.fold_left
    (fun x a ->
      List.fold_left
       (fun y b ->
         b::a::y
       )
       x
       l2
   )
   []
   l1
 )
;;
```

For the cartesian product, just change

```
b::a::y
```

into

```
(a,b)::y
```

Answer (score 2):

I would break the problem into two sub problems:

- Firstly consider a function appendeach with takes a value and a list and returns the result of adding that value infront of each item in the list

  ```
  let rec appendeach x lst = 
    match lst with 
      [] -> [] 
    | hd::tl -> x::hd::(appendeach x tl);;
  ```
- Then consider a function product with takes two lists and calls appendeach for each item in the first list and the whole second list

  ```
   let rec product lst1 lst2 = 
     match lst1 with 
       [] -> []
     | hd::tl -> (appendeach hd lst2)@(product tl lst2);;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation for any number of lists, based on Python's `itertools.product`.

The lists all have to be the same type, because the products we return will themselves be (necessarily homogenous) lists.

```ml
let product pools =
  let result = ref [[]] in
  List.iter (fun pool ->
      result := List.concat_map (fun y ->
          List.map (fun x ->
              List.append x [y]
            ) !result
        ) pool
    ) pools;
  !result
```

```ml
product [["a";"b"]; ["1";"2"]; ["$";"%"]];;
- : string list list =
[["a"; "1"; "$"]; ["b"; "1"; "$"]; ["a"; "2"; "$"]; ["b"; "2"; "$"];
 ["a"; "1"; "%"]; ["b"; "1"; "%"]; ["a"; "2"; "%"]; ["b"; "2"; "%"]]
```

If you then need a flattened list you can wrap it in `List.concat` as per the other answers:

```ml
List.concat (product [["a";"b"]; ["1";"2"]]);;
- : string list = ["a"; "1"; "b"; "1"; "a"; "2"; "b"; "2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A very imperative (java-like or C-like) solution so I'm not sure it will help; in functional languages like OCaml is usually expected recursion rather than loops. But it works:

```
let cartesianProduct list1 list2 =
    let product = ref [] in
        for i = 0 to List.length list1 -1 do
            for j = 0 to List.length list2 -1 do
                product:= !product@[List.nth list1 i]@[List.nth list2 j]
            done;
        done;
    !product;;
```

Comment: This is insanely inefficient. If it were a pair of arrays it wouldn't be so bad, but because these are singly linked lists where `List.nth` and `@` are both `O(n)`, this is something like `O(4n^3)`.

Comment: Small note: constants don't count in big-O notation, so O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

Mapping is a very natural solution to this problem [as shown in Victor Nicollet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893700/15261315). It's is not tail-recursive, though, and for large enough data samples, a stack overflow will occur. Now, you could use folds [as shown in thmscarle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10895940/15261315).

*Or, you could make mapping tail-recursive.*

```
let map_tailrec f lst =
  let rec aux lst k =
    match lst with 
    | [] -> k []
    | x::xs -> aux xs (fun i -> k (f x :: i))
  in
  aux lst Fun.id
```

Which we can use to mildly modify Victor Nicollet's function

```
let cartesian l l' = 
  l 
  |> map_tailrec (fun e -> map_tailrec (fun e' -> (e,e')) l') 
  |> List.concat
```

Of course, `List.concat` isn't tail-recursive either, so we have to fix that next.

```
let concat_tailrec lsts =
  let rec aux lsts k = 
    match lsts with
    | [] -> k []
    | []::xs -> aux xs k
    | (x::x')::xs -> aux (x'::xs) (fun i -> k (x :: i))
  in
  aux lsts Fun.id
```

And now we can write:

```
let cartesian l l' = 
  l 
  |> map_tailrec (fun e -> map_tailrec (fun e' -> (e,e')) l') 
  |> concat_tailrec
```

Doing this, `cartesian` remains very familiar, but by addressing the tail recursion issue with the smaller components, we have addressed the problem with the whole.