# Permutations of two lists

Tags: ocaml

I have a `char list` in OCAML. I would like to create a `( (char * bool) list) list` of every combination of the `char`s with `true` and `false`.

What I have guess I have to do is something like a `List.fold_left`, but I am not quite sure how to pull it off.

This is the outline that I tried (OCAML syntax, but not run-able):

```
let rec var_perm var_list options = 
    match var_list with
        | [] -> options
        | x :: v' ->
            ((x, true) :: (var_perm_intern v')) :: ((x, false) :: (var_perm_intern v'))
;;

let all_options = var_perm ['a';'b'] [];;
```

should return

```
[
    [('a',true);('b',true)];
    [('a',true);('b',false)];
    [('a',false);('b',true)];
    [('a',false);('b'false)];
]
```

**Edit:** Another example:

```
let all_options = var_perm ['u';'w';'y'] [];;
```

should return (order is not important)

```
[
    [('u',false);('w',false);('y',false)];
    [('u',false);('w',false);('y',true )];
    [('u',false);('w',true );('y',false)];
    [('u',false);('w',true );('y',true )];
    [('u',true );('w',false);('y',false)];
    [('u',true );('w',false);('y',true )];
    [('u',true );('w',true );('y',false)];
    [('u',true );('w',true );('y',true )];
]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893521/how-to-take-product-of-two-list-in-ocaml

Comment: @GeneT Not the same as what I am looking for. That returns a single list containing all the options. I need a list of lists (as you can see in the question).

Answer (score 2):

You're close to a correct solution. Specifically:

- you must remove the `_intern` suffix in your recursive call
- the "options" parameter is useless (look at how you do your recursive call, passing only *one* parameter `v'`), so you must find out what to return in the `[]` case
- the concatenation of "the results of `v'`, plus `true` for the head var" and " the results of `v'`, plus `false` for the head var" should be written `foo @ bar` rather than `foo :: bar`, because those are two lists you're concatenating, not one element added to a list.

Comment: I was using the `options` as an accumulator. I know that they don't match, but I was not sure if I really needed it. I will try a bit more.

Comment: "I need an accumulator" is often a good way to, out of habit, not look at the problem in the face and derive a solution from this specification. What is the set of options for an empty list? Given a set of options for `li`, what set of options should be returned for `var :: li`? There, your function.

Comment: Your third suggestion about `foo @ bar` does not produce a list of lists like I am looking for. Thoughts?

Comment: Thought: you somehow got my (admittedly vague) suggestion in a different way than I intended. I described the three steps that lead me to a working function from your code, so I know it works. I'm just saying that `(@)` has type `'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list`, and that's what you need to use somewhere.