# Combination of a list with permutations of another list

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I have two lists:

```
object = ['square','circle','triangle']
description = ['red','green']
```

I want as output a list of dictionaries:

```
{'square': 'red', 'circle': 'red', 'triangle': 'red'}
{'square': 'red', 'circle': 'red', 'triangle': 'green'}
{'square': 'green', 'circle': 'red', 'triangle': 'green'}
```

etc.

So the objects don't repeat, but the descriptions may. Each dictionary has as its keys the original list of objects.

I'm not sure of the name of the algorithm I want, so I'm having trouble finding the correct one. (I've looked at [permutations of two lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953194/permutations-of-two-lists-in-python), but that's seeking a different result. [Permutations of two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740866/permutations-of-two-lists) is the same question, but using OCAML.)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of "Cartesian product giving a dictionary", but not of "Operation on every pair of element in a list".

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `object` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `object` type. It won't hurt anything here, but it looks weird in a decent syntax highlighter. And it will cause weird error messages if the subsequent code uses Python 2 new-style class definitions: `class MyClass(object):`.

Comment: I made some wrong comments initially, fixed some wrong duplicate closures with other wrong ones, re-read, and then fixed the duplicate links properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to generate all possible combinations of your `descriptions`.

Then create a dictionary with the `objects` as keys and the "combination" as values:

```
>>> import itertools

>>> objects = ['square','circle','triangle']
>>> description = ['red','green']

>>> [dict(zip(objects, comb)) for comb in itertools.product(description, repeat=len(objects))]
[{'circle': 'red', 'square': 'red', 'triangle': 'red'},
 {'circle': 'red', 'square': 'red', 'triangle': 'green'},
 {'circle': 'green', 'square': 'red', 'triangle': 'red'},
 {'circle': 'green', 'square': 'red', 'triangle': 'green'},
 {'circle': 'red', 'square': 'green', 'triangle': 'red'},
 {'circle': 'red', 'square': 'green', 'triangle': 'green'},
 {'circle': 'green', 'square': 'green', 'triangle': 'red'},
 {'circle': 'green', 'square': 'green', 'triangle': 'green'}]
```