# Input two lists, match the contents with each other

Tags: ocaml, cartesian-product

I am trying to create a function in OCaml with this method signature:

```
let generate_deck (suits : suit list) (ranks : rank list) : card list =
```

Suit, Rank, and Card are defined as this:

```
type suit = Clubs | Spades | Hearts | Diamonds

type rank =  Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten |
             Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type card = rank * suit
```

The function should then return a list where each suit is paired with all possible ranks. I know I need to use pattern matching to do this but I am really confused as to how.

Answer (score 0):

First, write a function `rank list -> suit -> card list` to generate a full suit, then `map` this on all suits an `concat`.

```
type suit = Clubs | Spades | Hearts | Diamonds

type rank =  Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten |
             Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type card = rank * suit

let generate_suit ranks suit =
    List.map (fun rank -> suit, rank) ranks;;

let generate_deck suits ranks =
    List.concat (List.map (generate_suit ranks) suits);;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there an alternate way to do it that doesn't involve the map and concat functions? Maybe with pattern matching?

Comment: It's considered bad practice to `open` modules like you do here, since it pollutes the namespace and makes it difficult to see where functions are defined. You should instead just qualify the functions, i.e. write `List.map` and `List.concat`.

Comment: @Mika Actually, I'll just give you a hint: you can write map and concat yourself with pattern matching. From your profile I can guess you are taking COMP302 at McGill University. And trust me that professor Pientka has a below zero tolerance for plagiarism, so you do not want to get the answer from Stackoverflow.

Comment: Although, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893700/5079316

Comment: Thanks for the help! I wasn't looking for a complete solution, just a push in the right direction so this has really helped!